# Parallels Desktop and Resharper

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, .net-framework, resharper

I am using MacBook Pro and I am developing .net application in Parallels Desktop 9 with Windows 8 as the guest OS. All is great, but I have one small issue with Resharper "Go To Symbol" feature. The problem is when I am using parallel in the "Coherence" mode, the "Go To Symbol" feature is terribly slow and it only happen in "Coherence" mode.

Anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check this thread out: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?267666-How-to-disable-window-shadows-in-PDfM-8-Coherence-mode

There I share my experience with it and results of contacting Parallels support.

Quick answer: such behavior is a documented bug in PD, it's not clear when it'll be fixed. It works better in PD9, than in PD8.

Suggestion: post a bug report to Parallels, it'll probably raise priority for a fix.